# Provisioning simple Windows EC2 instance wants to destroy VPC and resources

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I've dumbed down my code and reproduced my issue...  I've created a simple VPC with just one subnet.

Using Terraform v0.12.1 on Windows

After creating the VPC I'm just attempting to deploy an EC2 instance (Server 2019 Core)... when running a 'terraform plan' for this instance, it wants to create the EC2 instance, and destroy the one subnet and VPC

Just curious as to whether or not anyone has had this issue, or has any ideas as to what the heck is causing the destroy?

After simplifying the plan to almost nothing...
Order of operations:
1. Terraform apply to create VPC
2. Note the subnet ID and modify the plan for the EC2 instance to use it
3. Terraform plan against the plan for the EC2 instance

```
# VPC plan
provider "aws" {
    region = "ca-central-1"
    profile = "blablabla"
}

resource "aws_vpc" "dev" {
    #cidr_block = "10.0.0.0/16"
    cidr_block = "10.0.2.0/24"
    enable_dns_hostnames = true
}

resource "aws_subnet" "private-subnet" {
    vpc_id = "${aws_vpc.dev.id}"
    cidr_block = "10.0.2.0/24"
}
```

```
# EC2 plan
provider "aws" {
 profile = "blablabla"
 region     = "ca-central-1"
}

data "aws_ami" "latest-win2019-core" {
most_recent = true
owners = ["amazon"]

  filter {
    name = "name"
    values = ["Windows_Server-2019-English-Core-Base*"]
  }
}

resource "aws_instance" "win-2019-core" {
  ami           = "${data.aws_ami.latest-win2019-core.id}"
  instance_type = "t2.micro"
  subnet_id = "subnet-04801d62b22ad8dc0"
}
```

Plan output:

```
  # aws_subnet.private-subnet will be destroyed
  - resource "aws_subnet" "private-subnet" {
      - arn                             = "arn:aws:ec2:ca-central-1:3...." -> null
      - assign_ipv6_address_on_creation = false -> null
      - availability_zone               = "ca-central-1a" -> null
      - availability_zone_id            = "cac1-az1" -> null
      - cidr_block                      = "10.0.2.0/24" -> null
      - id                              = "subnet-04801d62b22ad8dc0" -> null
      - map_public_ip_on_launch         = false -> null
      - owner_id                        = "366481676110" -> null
      - tags                            = {} -> null
      - vpc_id                          = "vpc-0fd0f22b95456364d" -> null
    }

  # aws_vpc.dev will be destroyed
  - resource "aws_vpc" "dev" {
      - arn                              = "arn:aws:ec2:ca-central-1:3...." -> null
      - assign_generated_ipv6_cidr_block = false -> null
      - cidr_block                       = "10.0.2.0/24" -> null
      - default_network_acl_id           = "acl-0edb8e4b47405fa20" -> null
      - default_route_table_id           = "rtb-046e1eeb314d510b0" -> null
      - default_security_group_id        = "sg-031e10e2228957ead" -> null
      - dhcp_options_id                  = "dopt-1ae43972" -> null
      - enable_dns_hostnames             = true -> null
      - enable_dns_support               = true -> null
      - id                               = "vpc-0fd0f22b95456364d" -> null
      - instance_tenancy                 = "default" -> null
      - main_route_table_id              = "rtb-046e1eeb314d510b0" -> null
      - owner_id                         = "366481676110" -> null
      - tags                             = {} -> null
    }

Plan: 1 to add, 0 to change, 2 to destroy.
```

Comment: Are you using the same state file for 2 different directories of .tf files?

Comment: Yes, I am using the same state file

Comment: And yes, two different directories of .tf files

Comment: Yeah, don't do this. One state file per `terraform apply`. It might be worth reading the Terraform docs, particularly around state before you go any further.